# Is there a term to refer both var and val?

Tags: scala, variables

In Java, I can use the term variable to refer to any field.

But since Scala have both var and val, I can't think of a term that I can use to mean any value regardless of it being var or val. Variable is not a good term since I'm not comfortable with calling a val a variable.

Is there a good term to use?

Comment: `mutable reference` for `var` and `immutable reference` for `val` and `reference` for both.

Comment: @Sarveh But what about a var or val containing a primitive declared locally, such as an `int`, which contains the value itself?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Well... how about we altogether avoid primitives... (just so that we can have a name for the thing... :D) ? Or we can call them just `primitives`

Comment: Scala as a language doesn't really distinguish between objects and primitives the way Java does... But it would still not really be technically correct to call them references...

Comment: @Jasper-M That's the thing, technically they may not be references :)

Answer (score 1):

When I have questions like these, I usually refer to the language specification.

The specification states two sections, *value declaration* and *variable declaration*:

> ### 4.1 Value Declarations and Definitions:

```
Dcl          ::=  ‘val’ ValDcl
ValDcl       ::=  ids ‘:’ Type 
PatVarDef    ::=  ‘val’ PatDef 
PatDef       ::=  Pattern2 {‘,’ Pattern2} [‘:’ Type] ‘=’ Expr 
ids          ::=  id {‘,’ id}
```

> A value declaration `val x: T` introduces x as a name of a
>   value of type T.

---

> ### 4.2 Variable Declarations and Definitions

```
Dcl            ::=  ‘var’ VarDcl
PatVarDef      ::=  ‘var’ VarDef
VarDcl         ::=  ids ‘:’ Type
VarDef         ::=  PatDef
                 |  ids ‘:’ Type ‘=’ ‘_’
```

> A variable declaration `var x: T` is equivalent to the declarations of both a getter function x and a setter function x_=:

There may not be a uniform calling convention to the two of them, and yet they are usually used interchangeably. I like to think of `val`'s as an immutable value in which a reference to it may not change, and a `var` as a mutable reference. Note that these may not always hold, since when we talk about primitives the underlying value is the actual bytes containing the value.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala we refer `val`,`var`and`def` as `CLASS FIELD`. when you say `class field` then it include all `val`,`var`and`def` but In Scala only for `val` and `var` there is no specific `term`.
this information i get is from Book of Scala by `martin odersky`.
Hope my Answer clears your dough.

Comment: Well... it really does not answer the question. And also... the information is largely misleading. Consider the case of `def a(i: Int): Int { val t = "t"; i }`, here that `val t` is NOT a `class field`.

Comment: i was telling you in general this is written in book.

Comment: No book will have that written in it. In Scala you DO NOT refer `val`, `var` and `def` as `CLASS FIELD`. You may refer to `class members` as `class fields`.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Programming in Scala, First Edition](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/first-steps-in-scala.html) (emphasis mine):

> Scala has two kinds of **variables**, vals and vars.